# calling a jquery function in form submit button

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery function:

```
function post_form(form_id) {
    $( form_id ).submit(function(e) {
        CheckRequired(e);
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        LoadModalBody('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>', 'Loading');
        $.ajax({
            url : '/section' + formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                LoadModal('/section' + formURL, 'Mileage');

                //$("body").html(data);
                //data: return data from server
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //if fails
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
    });
}
```

i want to call it in a HTML form submit button

i know i can use `onClick="post_form();` but how do i put the form id in the call, i think using `this` would be the submit button and not the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This enought:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(e){
  // code for validate or ither staff
});
```

Just remove first and last line of code in your example.

Comment: if i call the function inside this, could i use $(this); to get the ID of the form?

Comment: Yes, you can use $(this).attr('id') for getting ID of form tag.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you put this code at the top of the page and attribute it directly like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
        ...
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="my-form">
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Click me to submit form" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i use $(this); inside the .submit when calling the function ?

Comment: Yes. Inside the function `$(this)` will be the form wrapped in jQuery.

Comment: so i could use $('#my-form').submit(function(e) { form_post($(this)); });

Comment: oh you wouldn't have to call form_post anymore. Instead you're just telling the form what to do on submission.

Comment: but i want to run this function to post the form

Comment: There are two thing happening above. One of them is the use of `$(function(){});` which is similar to `document.onready`. This means that the encapsulated javascript will not run until the rest of the page is rendered. At that time the form with the id "my-form" will exist and you won't need to dynamically figure our the id.

Comment: Yes, when the submit button is pressed. it will call the function.

Comment: but you didnt add the function in your example above?

Comment: The post_form function is not needed. The function represented by the first ellipses is what you really want to get to. Now you're going straight to it.

Comment: sorry im not understanding - how can it call the function if its not being called

Comment: jQuery is creating an [event listener](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) for you that will call the function `function(e) {
        CheckRequired(e);...`  when the form is submitted.

Comment: but your not actually calling the function at all - this doesnt make sense

Comment: The even listener is. If you need more help or clarity referring to the jQuery docs on the [submit method](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) my be helpful.

Comment: how is it calling the function when you dont physically put any code to call it?

Comment: the jquery or HTML form has no idea where to post the data to

Comment: `$('#my-form').submit()` is the code that is going to call it.

Comment: so i need to add post_form(); to actually call the function?

Comment: You can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x8k2mbk7/1/). I'm sort of at a loss for what else to tell you. Define event listener -> click submit -> event fires -> event listener picks it up -> calls function.

Comment: even in that fiddle you are not calling the function so the function cannot fire (the function i am referring to is the one i have created)

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question. If you are really set on using the  post_form function then this would work `onClick="post_form(this.id);`